# spinner value Not save into database php mysql android

Tags: php, android, spinner

How To Save spinner value save into mysql Database..i am trying to save Spinner Value in To mysql database But Not save..how to Resolve Problem..
How to do this and what I need to do to insert item in PHP?.

help to Resolve my Problem...advance Thanks..........................

Here is Java Code...

```
 package com.example.spinner.Category;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.spinner.Category1;
    import com.example.spinner.HttpParse;
    import com.example.spinner.MainActivity;
    import com.example.spinner.R;
    import com.example.spinner.ServiceHandler;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CategoryMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        EditText CatsName;
        Button RegisterCategory, ShowCategory;
        String CatsNameHolder, CatsTypeHolder;
        Boolean CheckEditTextcats ;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String finalResult ;
        private Spinner spinnerFood;
        // array list for spinner adapter
        private ArrayList<Category1> categoriesList;
        private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://10.0.2.2/food_api/get_categories.php";
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
        String HttpURL = "http://10.0.2.2/phpfiles/CatsRegister.php";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_main);




            categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category1>();

            // spinner item select listener

            // Add new category click event


            new CategoryMainActivity.GetCategories().execute();


            CatsName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CatsName);
            spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinType);


            RegisterCategory = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
            ShowCategory = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonShow);

            RegisterCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // Checking whether EditText is Empty or Not
                    CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                    if(CheckEditTextcats){

                        // If EditText is not empty and CheckEditText = True then this block will execute.

                        CategoryRegistration(CatsNameHolder,CatsTypeHolder);

                    }
                    else {

                        // If EditText is empty then this block will execute .
                        Toast.makeText(CategoryMainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
            });

            ShowCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowAllCategory.class);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
        private void populateSpinner() {
            List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();



            for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
                lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
            }

            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            spinnerAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinnerFood.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        }
        public void CategoryRegistration(final String C_Name, final String C_Type){

            class CategoryRegistrationClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CategoryMainActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                    super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(CategoryMainActivity.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    hashMap.put("Catsname",params[0]);

                    hashMap.put("spinType",params[1]);



                    finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);

                    return finalResult;
                }
            }

            CategoryRegistrationClass categoryRegistrationClass = new CategoryRegistrationClass();

            categoryRegistrationClass.execute(C_Name,C_Type);
        }


        public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

            CatsNameHolder = CatsName.getText().toString();


            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(CatsNameHolder))
            {

                CheckEditTextcats = false;

            }
            else {

                CheckEditTextcats = true ;
            }

        }
        private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryMainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
                String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

                if (json != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                        if (jsonObj != null) {
                            JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                                    .getJSONArray("categories");

                            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                                Category1 cat = new Category1(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                        catObj.getString("name"));
                                categoriesList.add(cat);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                populateSpinner();
            }

        }
    }
    </code>
```

Here is Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">



    <TextView
        android:text="Category Registertion Form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Category Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/CatsName" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Select Type"/>

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinType"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CatsName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinType"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit" />
    <Button
        android:text="Show All Records"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        android:id="@+id/buttonShow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your error Log here @Munawar Akram

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
}

ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategoryMainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerFood.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not get the selected items from your spinner, get it like this:

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

or any data type you want, but make sure to use the `getSelectedItem()` to retrieve a value.